# cabal install errors-1.3.1 fails

Tags: haskell, cabal, heist

I'm trying to install the newest version of Heist, but `errors-1.3.1` which is a dependency fails to install. Any suggestions for how to get past this?

```
$ cabal install errors-1.3.1
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring errors-1.3.1...
Building errors-1.3.1...
Preprocessing library errors-1.3.1...
[1 of 5] Compiling Data.EitherR     ( Data/EitherR.hs, dist/build/Data/EitherR.o )
[2 of 5] Compiling Control.Error.Util ( Control/Error/Util.hs, dist/build/Control/Error/Util.o )

Control/Error/Util.hs:74:10:
    Could not deduce (Monad m) arising from a use of `fmap'
    from the context (Functor m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 fmapRT :: Functor m => (a -> b) -> EitherT l m a -> EitherT l m b
      at Control/Error/Util.hs:74:1-13
    Possible fix:
      add (Monad m) to the context of
        the type signature for
          fmapRT :: Functor m => (a -> b) -> EitherT l m a -> EitherT l m b
    In the expression: fmap
    In an equation for `fmapRT': fmapRT = fmap
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
errors-1.3.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: Version 1.3.1 is old, perhaps you should `cabal update` and try installing 1.4.1.  If this was a dep selected by cabal then use --constraint 'errors == 1.4.1'

Comment: Why does the newest Heist (0.11.0) depend on errors-1.3.*?

Comment: The git repo for Heist actually corrects this problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I just released the latest code to hackage, so this should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this in the latest errors, which is 1.4.1 (1.4.0 has a mistake where I don't export the EitherT and MaybeT types).  I've added upper bounds on the either dependency this time to prevent it happening in the future.